# jquery update div background element

Tags: php, jquery, css, html, background

Alright not sure what to do and i am honestly bit lost. What I am trying to do is upload a file to site via jQuery and push it to PHP which then deletes original image file and makes a a copy of it called header.jpg and pushes it where it needs to go. That part works with no problem. The problem here is how would I go about updating the div element if the header.jpg image is the background?

Note: no matter what the img will always be header.jpg but it needs to be re-cached by browser and outputed to user without page refresh

Here is how the header div is layed out

```
<div id="headerEmpty"></div>
         <div id="pageName">
             <h2><?php echo $pageName; ?></h2>
         </div>
         <?php if ( $_SESSION['signed_in'] == true ) { ?>
         <div id="header" style="background-image:url(uploads/header.jpg);">
             <span class="edit" fn="header">
                 <img src="uploads/icon/16/018.png" />
             </span>
             <div class="fn_menu" style="display:none;"></div>
         </div>
         <?php } else { ?>
         <div id="header"></div>
         <?php } ?>
```

and here is the jquery bit which displays loader and auto-starts the upload process

```
$('#photoimg').live('change', function() { 

        $("#preview").html('');
        $("#preview").html('<img src="uploads/icon/16/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
        $("#imageform").ajaxForm(
        { 
        target: '#header',
        success : function(data) {
        $("#header").html(data).fadeIn('fast');
        }           
        }).submit();
     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to update the image, change it's source. You can append a time-stamp to the source so it will not come from the browser's cache. In PHP that would be something like:

```
<div id="headerEmpty"></div>
         <div id="pageName">
             <h2><?php echo $pageName; ?></h2>
         </div>
         <?php if ( $_SESSION['signed_in'] == true ) { ?>
         <div id="header" style="background-image:url(uploads/header.jpg?_=<?php echo time(); ?>);">
             <span class="edit" fn="header">
                 <img src="uploads/icon/16/018.png" />
             </span>
             <div class="fn_menu" style="display:none;"></div>
         </div>
         <?php } else { ?>
         <div id="header"></div>
         <?php } ?>
```

The time-stamp should just be ignored and the image will be downloaded each update.

### Update

Ok, I see now that the background image is on the element you are replacing the HTML of. You could use jQuery to update the `url()` of the image:

```
    success : function(data) {
        var theDate = new Date();
        $("#header").css('background-image', 'uploads/header.jpg?_=' + theDate.getTime()).html(data).fadeIn('fast');
    }
```

You could also use PHP to output the `#header` element and use `replaceWith()` instead of `.html()`:

```
    success : function(data) {
        $("#header").replaceWith(data).fadeIn('fast');
    }
```

This assumes that your PHP output now looks like this:

```
     <div id="header" style="background-image:url(uploads/header.jpg?_=1234567890);">
         <span class="edit" fn="header">
             <img src="uploads/icon/16/018.png" />
         </span>
         <div class="fn_menu" style="display:none;"></div>
     </div>
```

Comment: i am aware of using timestamp, date and what ever else. The image uploads/header.jpg is not updated on the page its updated on the server via AJAX and a new copy is forced to over-write the original. However there are 0 refresh on the page resulting in the image still staying there, since there is no refresh timestamp is useless as the page does not refresh to update the timestamp

Comment: @Cl' I added a few examples of how to apply the time-stamp to the `background-image`.

Comment: thanks for the example but I am still can't get it to work. Say would there be an easier way instead of using div to update src?